# Cannot resolve NPM module which seems to have installed successfully

Tags: module, npm, webpack, webstorm, npm-install

I have installed a few modules doing `npm install --save ng2-redux redux redux-actions redux-promise`. If I do `npm list | grep "redux"` I get:

```
├── ng2-redux@3.0.5
├─┬ redux@3.5.2
├─┬ redux-actions@0.12.0
├─┬ redux-promise@0.5.3
```

And in my `package.json` I can find them as well:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...

  "ng2-redux": "3.0.5",
  "redux": "3.5.2",
  "redux-actions": "0.12.0",
  "redux-promise": "0.5.3",

  ...
}
```

The problem is that while `ng2-redux` and `redux` both work fine:

```
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux';
```

`redux-actions` and `redux-promise` both throw a `Cannot resolve file 'redux-actions'/'redux-promise'` when trying to import them, that appears both in the IDE (WebStorm 11.0.4) and in Webpack:

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
```

The errors says:

```
ERROR in ../src/.../app.component.ts
(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux-promise'.
```

However...

```
import 'redux-actions';
import 'redux-promise';
```

...works just fine.

I have already tried to remove the `node_modules` folder and reinstall everything with `npm cache clear`, `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` and it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have d.ts file under node_modules directory. Try

```
npm install --save-dev @types/redux-promise
```

to acquire the type information of the module.